# Scala type alias naming rules?

Tags: scala, naming, type-alias

I tried to do a Google search but I failed to find anything relevant because of the symbology involved.

I know this compiles `type ==>[A, B] = Map[A, B]` but this does not `type m==>[A, B] = Map[A, B]`. Also, this does not compile `type =m=>[A, B] = Map[A, B]`.

Also, I know that these are equivalent `def foo: Int ==> String = ???` and `def foo: ==>[Int, String] = ???`. But I could not find any official documentation where these rules are specified? Where is it specified that I can subsitute the 2 type params to be on either side of the type alias? What if I had 3 type parameters? If I have this: `type ==>[A, B, C]`, how can I do something like `def foo: A ==> B ==> C`?

Comment: Additionally to Erik's answers: the doc about the identifiers legal syntax is [Chapter 1.1](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/01-lexical-syntax.html) of the The Scala Language Speciﬁcation.

Comment: And the doc about the infix types is [Chapter 3.2.8](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html) of the SLS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala identifier names cannot contain a mix of symbols and characters. This applies uniformly on method as well as type and type constructor names.

```
scala> type =m=>[A, B] = Map[A, B]
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but '=' found.
       type =m=>[A, B] = Map[A, B]
            ^

scala> type ===>[A, B] = Map[A, B]
defined type alias $eq$eq$eq$greater

scala> type mmmm[A, B] = Map[A, B]
defined type alias mmmm
```

compare with:

```
scala> def foo = 3
foo: Int

scala> def === = 3
$eq$eq$eq: Int

scala> def =foo= = 3
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but '=' found.
       def =foo= = 3
           ^
```

The only exception is `foo_<symbol-here>` but which will not help you name something `=m=>`.

```
scala> def foo_? = 3
foo_$qmark: Int

scala> def foo_* = 3
foo_$times: Int

scala> def foo_==> = 3
foo_$eq$eq$greater: Int
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What about part II of my question? Where are the rules for `A ==> B` is same as `==> [A, B]` defined? What if I had `type ==>[A, B, C]`? How can I put the type alias "in between" the type params?

Comment: This should get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200380/whats-the-name-of-this-scala-infix-syntax-for-specifying-type-params

Comment: Aah, these are called "infix type syntax"