# Scala Play framework FunctionalCanBuild explain

Tags: scala, playframework, play-json

For curiosity sake, for those who study Scala, please explain what the hell that implementation of `FunctionalCanBuild` is:

So, it is possible to create custom Json `Writes` for a class in play framework, like this:

```
implicit val locationWrites: Writes[Location] = (
  (JsPath \ "lat").write[Double] and
  (JsPath \ "long").write[Double]
)(unlift(Location.unapply))
```

The `and` is method defined in `FunctionalBuilderOps` and returns `FunctionalBuilder[M]#CanBuild2` which in turn returns `FunctionalBuilder[M]#CanBuild3` and so on till `FunctionalBuilder[M]#CanBuild22`.

So why 22? What if my model has 23 fields?
From Scala point of view how to understand this:

```
fu.fmap[A1 ~ A2, B](canBuild(m1, m2), { case a1 ~ a2 => f(a1, a2) })
```

Why `~` (and where it is defined) called on generics?

I know, this question may look bit complicated, but stackoverflow is the only hope I have, no googling no scala docs help to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`~` is defined here: https://github.com/playframework/play-json/blob/master/play-functional/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/functional/Products.scala#L9

`A ~ B` is like a pair `(A, B)`.

22 is magic number in Scala:

[Why are scala functions limited to 22 parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152223/why-are-scala-functions-limited-to-22-parameters)

https://underscore.io/blog/posts/2016/10/11/twenty-two.html

Comment: Thanks much, that clarifying bit. But why A ~ B is called on generics inside square brackets? [A1 ~ A2, B] does A1 ~ A2 mean some generic which should pair of A1 and A2?

Comment: `A1 ~ A2` is the same as `~[A1, A2]`. It's syntax sugar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200380/whats-the-name-of-this-scala-infix-syntax-for-specifying-type-params